# What is the command for starting a WSGI server for Django?

Tags: python, django

I've developed an application in Django that I usually run in development mode:

**python manage.py runserver**

I do the same for my deployed instances - obviously a security issue that I now want to resolve.

From the Django docs, its not clear to me how to:

- For simplicity sake, I picked wsgi (over asgi): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/ . From this page, its not clear to me how my 'runserver' command changes to run the wsgi server over the development server. Should I run the wsgi.py file? That doesn't seem to do anything.
- From the page above, its not clear whether wsgi is actually a server, or more a platform/type of servers. Do I need to use uwsgi/uvicorn/etc. instead?
- I'm testing on windows - uvicorn is unix only, so I tried uwsgi, but thats giving me this error message: AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'uname' - I guess its Unix only as well
- So I'm using the docker image I was already building for deployment - uwsgi is giving me issues again because my docker image has no compiler, so I try now with gunicorn.
- that should be easy: **gunicorn project.wsgi**, which gives me:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project/wsgi'

- my folder structure looks like:
- root-folder

  - project

    - wsgi.py
    - settings.py
  - django_app_1
  - django_app_2
    manage.py

As the manual says, the gunicorn command should work as long as you run the gunicorn command from the same location as manage.py - which is what I'm doing.

I guess I'm missing something very obvious - who knows what?

Comment: Have you tried to run `gunicorn project.wsgi` from the folder containing the `project` module?

Answer (score 0):

The `wsgi.py` file just gives you a WSGI compatible application that a WSGI HTTP server (such as Gunicorn) can run.

I guess you have to run `gunicorn project.wsgi` from the root folder (that one containing the `project` module).

Typically, the directory containing manage.py and the module in which wsgi.py resides are one and the same. But not in your case.